# grails data binding collection

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Any idea why next example about Binding To Collections And Maps, in The Grails Framework - Reference Documentation, fails with below exception indicated???

```
class Band {
    String name
    static hasMany = [albums: Album]
    List albums
}
class Album {
    String title
    Integer numberOfTracks
}

def bindingMap = [name: 'Genesis', 
                  'albums[0]': [title: 'Foxtrot', numberOfTracks: 6], 
                  'albums[1]': [title: 'Nursery Cryme', numberOfTracks: 7]]
def band = new Band(bindingMap)

assert band.name == 'Genesis'
assert band.albums.size() == 2
assert band.albums[0].title == 'Foxtrot'
assert band.albums[0].numberOfTracks == 6
assert band.albums[1].title == 'Nursery Cryme'
assert band.albums[1].numberOfTracks == 7


≫ groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: albums[0] for class: Band Possible solutions: albums at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:15) at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:57) at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:37) at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.execute(ConsoleController.groovy:32) at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198) at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63) at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53) at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49) at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like this:

Album:

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Album.groovy
package demo

class Album {
    String title
    Integer numberOfTracks
}
```

Band:

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Band.groovy
package demo

class Band {
    String name
    static hasMany = [albums: Album]
    List albums
}
```

This unit test will pass:

```
// test/unit/demo/BandSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(Band)
class BandSpec extends Specification {

    void "test constructor binding"() {
        given:
        def bindingMap = [name: 'Genesis',
                          'albums[0]': [title: 'Foxtrot', numberOfTracks: 6],
                          'albums[1]': [title: 'Nursery Cryme', numberOfTracks: 7]]
        when:
        def band = new Band(bindingMap)

        then:
        band.name == 'Genesis'
        band.albums.size() == 2
        band.albums[0].title == 'Foxtrot'
        band.albums[0].numberOfTracks == 6
        band.albums[1].title == 'Nursery Cryme'
        band.albums[1].numberOfTracks == 7
    }
}
```

That code is in the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/bindingissue.

One thing that might cause the problem you are seeing is if `Band` isn't being recognized as a domain class.  Make sure that class is defined under grails-app/domain/ somewhere.  The special data binding offered by Grails is generally not available in constructors.  Domain classes are an exception to that.

I hope that helps.

Comment: If `Band` is not a domain class then the `hasMany` property is meaningless.  If it isn't a domain class then you can remove `hasMany` and if you want to take advantage of the data binding mechanism that knows how to deal with things like "albums[0]" (and a whole bunch of other functionality) then you can't use the constructor but instead need to invoke the data binder explicitly.  For example, in a controller you could call something like `bindData(bandInstance, bindingMap)` where `bandInstance` is an instance of the `Band` class and `bindingMap` is the `Map` as described above.

Comment: Indeed I must pay more attention to details when reading reference documentation!!! In reference documention is said: The following code shows a simple example of populating a List of objects in a domain class ... I underline 'domain class'. Jeff, you are absolutely right for both cases you mention: binding for domain and not domain classes, I already tested for both. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that your `Band` class is not a domain class.  If that is the case, you can remove the `hasMany` declaration as it is meaningless outside of a domain class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that - in your binding map - you have chosen to name a property "albums[0]" instead of using a collection "albums" and giving it two entries. Groovy is looking for a list but you have made this expression a property. Create the albums first, then add them to the album-list.

Like this:

```
def bindingMap = [
  name: 'Genesis', 
  'albums': [
    [title: 'Foxtrot', numberOfTracks: 6], 
    [title: 'Nursery Cryme', numberOfTracks: 7]
  ]
]
```

Comment: This is not correct if Band is a domain class.  The domain class constructor knows how to deal with the "albums[0]" key in the Map.  Since `Band` defines the `hasMany` property, I assume it is a domain class.